# How to extract the Character just before a specified Substring in VB6

Tags: vb6

I want to extract the character just before a specified substring, this is what I have so far

```
Dim MyStr As variant, Z as variant, Z1 as variant

'the string to extract character from
MyStr="-4<3x-6<12"

'locate the "<" in the string set it as value of Variable Z
Z= InstrRev(MyStr, "<")

If Z then MsgBox "string is" & Mid$
```

`Mid$` represents the bit I can't figure out.

How do I return the value 6, which is the character after the `<`

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that InstrRev returns the position of "<" so you just have to substract 1 to find the character in front of it.

I have some comments about your code though:

- Never declare your variables as *Variant* unless you really have to
- Name your variables in such a way that it is clear what type they are
- If you check wether a numeric variable is not 0, then check if it is not 0
- You dont use Z1

Keeping that in mind I changed your code into:

```
Dim MyStr As String
Dim lngZ As Long ', Z1 As String

'the string to extract character from
MyStr = "-4<3x-6<12"

'locate the "<" in the string set it as value of Variable Z
lngZ = InStrRev(MyStr, "<")

If lngZ > 0 Then
  MsgBox "string is " & Mid$(MyStr, lngZ - 1, 1)
End If
```